# Dual Boot XP - Ubuntu 10.10 (XP Installed first). Boot Loader issue

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, multi-boot, dell-inspiron

I have an old Dell laptop ( Inspiron 2650 ) I am trying to dual Boot XP Pro and Ubuntu 10.10. Windows XP Boots fine as it stands and the 40 GB disk is currently  partitioned as:

```
/dev/sda

 /dev/sda1  ntfs   10962 MB
 /dev/sda5  ext4   27798 MB
 /dev/sda6  swap   1244  MB
```

I am not sure on which partition  to install the linux Boot Loader.

I assume I do not want to install on `/dev/sda1` since it will mess with the Windows MBR? Will I be able to dual boot if I install in `/dev/sda5`? Or should it be installed on `/dev/sda`?

Comment: Windows has no MBR, the disk has an MBR. And the disk is /dev/sda (no 1 at the end).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, install it to MBR, then you can chainload XP...this will work out of the box on 10.10 with grub2 and should be automatically detected.

MBR is always /dev/sdx, no number so in this particular instance it's /dev/sda

Comment: Is MBR on /dev/sda or /dev/sda1 in this configuration?

Comment: edited to reflect where the mbr is located